# Cannot access action in Rails even with CanCanCan ability

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancancan

I have the following:

`questions_controller.rb`

```
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource #cancancan

  def index
    authorize! :view_all, @questions
```

`ability.rb`

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    ...
    elsif user.content_creator
      can [:index, :read, :create, :update], Unit
      can [:index, :read, :create, :update, :view_all], Question
```

`routes.rb`

```
  resources :units do
    resources :questions, only: [:index]
```

`Log`

```
Started GET "/units/1/questions" for ::1 at 2018-10-29 13:37:15 -0400
Processing by QuestionsController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"unit_id"=>"1"}
  User Load (8.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 13]]
You are not authorized to access this page.
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/dashboard
```

I confirmed the user is `content_creator`. I even restarted the server. The user *can* update a `Unit`. They cannot view the index of questions in that unit however. Why not?

If I put `can :manage, Question` at the beginning of `ability.rb`, then it is still unauthorized. If I use `can :manage, :all`, then it works.

Cancancan ~> 1.10

Answer (score 0):

I got rid of

```
# authorize! :view_all, @questions # prevents ContentCreators from viewing /units/1/questions
```

And changed

```
can :read, Question
```

To

```
can :show, Question
```

Everywhere else in `ability.rb` so only authorized viewers can see the index. This isn't a full answer however because it's still not clear why the original code did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I was also in a similar situation, after looking around what I found is this:

[Choosing actions](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/authorizing-controller-actions#choosing-actions)

```
class ProductsController < ActionController::Base
  load_and_authorize_resource
  def discontinue
    # Automatically does the following:
    # @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    # authorize! :discontinue, @product
  end
end
```

according to the commented out text, cancancan by default expect the action name to equal the ability, in your case you'll have to create a new action called

> def view_all

or else you'll have to create a sub rule for index.

Hope this helps.